# VSCode font ligature issue - Whose issue is it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using the most recent vscode, with fira code ttf font, and the ionide plugin to handle F# work.  I just noticed a problem that I think is new to the most recent vscode, and I think is a base VSCode issue, but I am not sure - it could be related to either ionide project, or the font. Or perhaps, electron or chrome is at at fault here?

In short, the -> symbol in F# used for lambda function declaration doesn't always get recognized.

[image: Various failures of the arrow symbol]

As you can see in the image above, the fun _ -> syntax used to declare an anonymous function does not render the -> as an arrow in all cases.  The addition of even a single parenthesis around the parameters will cause it to work right, as will the replacement of the parameter with a number (but not a letter).  The arrow ligature works fine in a big match statement, but it fails in this particular place.

I don't think its the font, as the font contains the right ligatures and works in most other places.  I think it has something to do with how/when vscode decides it should substitute the ligature.  Something about x -> makes it think it shouldn't do anything, but (_) -> is OK.  I suppose its possible that the ionide package somehow affects ligature detection, but I have seen no evidence of it.

So, before I report this to vscode as an issue, does anyone know for sure what is going on, and where the issue might be?

Edit: Another picture of it failing in a different context.  The multi parameter function renders correct, the single parameter function doesn't.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this looks like an issue with the `tmLanguage` file for F#.

As you can see when using the `Developer: Inpsect TM scopes` command, `-` and `>` are separate tokens ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qwun.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTH2t.png)) in the case where ligatures don't work, whereas in the working case, it's just a single token (`->`):

[image]

I actually reported a fairly similar ligature-related issue in [#19183](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19183) (for Haxe), but in that case it does *not* appear to be an issue with the grammar.

VSCode seems to use [ionide-fsgrammar](https://github.com/ionide/ionide-fsgrammar/) for its F# grammar, so you could report an issue there.

Comment: I believe you are right.  When I look more carefully at the language scope, `fun` starts the anonymous function scope.  When it works, it is because something after the fun has kicked it out of that scope. When it fails, its because it doesn't get kicked out of anonymous function scope until after it sees the - in the ->. Parens, numbers, etc, all things that are not expected in a function declaration according to its syntax, and so their presence fixes it as it kicks it out of the anon capture scope.

Comment: If anyone is interested, it seems that this has been [fixed](https://github.com/ionide/ionide-fsgrammar/commit/4f7e4e4568d6710b0250c4d9bde26915875aee90) already.  Not sure when it will make it into the release, but Mr. Cieślak releases often.